# Correctly cancelling and clearing a CancellationToken

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, cancellationtokensource

We have an `async` method called `GetThings` that goes off to 4 different providers and looks for results. Two of those providers are very fast and as a consequence are not written asynchronously however the other two providers are slow and are written asynchronously.

The GetThings method is called on a text change so a call to it should cancel previous calls. We do this using a CancellationTokenSource. The start of the GetThings method looks like this:

```
private async void GetThings()
{
    if (this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource != null &&
        this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested == false)
    {
        this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

We decided there is no point in returning anything from GetThings until all 4 providers have completed. We are accomplishing this using Task.WhenAll

```
var getThings1Task = this.GetThings1();
var getThings2Task = this.GetThings2();
var getThings3Task = this.GetThings3();
var getThings4Task = this.GetThings4();

await Task.WhenAll(getThings1Task, getThings2Task, getThings3Task, getThings4Task).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Read the .Result of each of the tasks

localSuggestions.Insert(0, getThings1Tasks.Result);
localSuggestions.Insert(1, getThings2Tasks.Result);
localSuggestions.Insert(2, getThings3Tasks.Result);
localSuggestions.Insert(3, getThings4Tasks.Result);

this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource = null;
```

Once we have read the .Result of each of the Task we set the quickEntryCancellationTokenSource to null. All this code is wrapped in the usual CancellationTokenSource exception handling. The start of GetThings3 passes the CancellationTokenSource down a layer if necessary.

```
private async Task<GroupedResult<string, SearchSuggestionItemViewModel>> GetThings3()
{
    List<Code> suggestions;

    if (this.SearchTerm.Length >= 3)
    {
        suggestions = await this.provider3.SearchAsync(this.SearchTerm, this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    else
    {
        suggestions = new List<Code>();
    }
```

**The problem we are seeing is that sometimes quickEntryCancellationTokenSource is null**. In my naivety i cannot see how that is possible as the CancellationTokenSource is created before the Tasks are waited on and not set to Null
until they are completed.

My questions are:

1. How is quickEntryCancellationTokenSource null?
2. Should we be synchronising access to the cancellationTokenSource?
   Because two of the four providers are so quick they never deal with
   the cancellationTokenSource.
3. Should all four methods be calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested?
4. Is it wrong that two of the four provider methods never await anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should we be synchronising access to the cancellationTokenSource? Because two of the four providers are so quick they never deal with the cancellationTokenSource.

You should synchronize access to the CTS, but not for that reason. The reason is because the `quickEntryCancellationTokenSource` field can be accessed from multiple threads.

If this is in the context of a UI thread, then you can just use the UI thread for synchronization:

```
// No ConfigureAwait(false); we want to only access the CTS from the UI thread.
await Task.WhenAll(getThings1Task, getThings2Task, getThings3Task, getThings4Task);
...
this.quickEntryCancellationTokenSource = null;
```

Also, I would consider passing the CT in to `getThings1Task` and the others, instead of having them read from a private variable.

> Should all four methods be calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested?

That's up to you. If your two "fast" provider methods don't take a CT, then you *could* check it, but it doesn't sound to me like it would provide any benefit.

> Is it wrong that two of the four provider methods never await anything?

If they're doing I/O, they should be using `await`, even if they *normally* are very fast. If they're not doing I/O, then I don't see much point in wrapping them in a `Task` at all. Presumably, the current code executes synchronously and always returns a completed task, so it's just a more complex way of just executing code synchronously in the first place. OTOH, if they're doing I/O but you don't have an asynchronous API for them (and since you're in a UI context), you can wrap them in a `Task.Run`.

> Once we have read the .Result of each of the Task

Consider using `await`, even for completed tasks. It'll make your exception handling code easier.

Comment: Isnt't it better to pass `CancellationToken` to all GetThingsX methods instead of using token source directly there? Then you don't need to synchronize access to token source at least in GetThingsX methods.

Comment: @Evk Yes, that's what I meant by "Also, I would consider passing the CT in to getThings1Task and the others, instead of having them read from a private variable."

Comment: Are you saying pass the CancellationToken as an argument for purely asthetic\organisational reasons? I still need it as a private variable so I can cancel it on subsequent calls right?

Comment: I've updated the question showing how we use .Result as I'm not sure what you are suggesting when you say "Consider using await"

Comment: Yes, the CTS still needs to be a private variable, but the methods only need the token, so that's all they should get. Regarding `Result`, I mean: `localSuggestions.Insert(0, await getThings1Tasks);`

Comment: Removing ConfigueAwait(false) stopped the NullReferenceException

Comment: @StephenCleary Cancellation token is co-operative by nature, then why not enough focus on passing it only via Task, and that it doesn't cancel an already running Task, which OP doesn't seems to be considering it, it will only cancel the Task that have not started. Also looking at the solution by OP, is it suggested to have a ConfigureAwait(false) on the Task.WhenAll call

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: I'm assuming that the OP's code is observing the `CancellationToken` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

My answers for your questions are:

1. No. `CancellationTokenSource` [is thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx), but access to the field itself should be synchronized. I have two suggestions to avoid this problem:

First, it is better to pass `CancellationToken` to `GetThings3` directly instead of referencing to global variable:

```cs
private async Task<GroupedResult<string, SearchSuggestionItemViewModel>> GetThings3(CancellationToken token) { ... }    

var getThings3Task = this.GetThings3(quickEntryCancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Second, it is better to avoid access to external variable. My suggestion is to use local `CancellationTokenSource`:

```cs
using (var localTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    var getThings1Task = this.GetThings1(localTokenSource.Token);
    ...
    await Task.WhenAll(...);
}
```

You may also want to think about `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(...)` if you want to create a token linked with global tokensource.

2. Yes, it is better to follow the previous suggestion and to call

```cs
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

But this is usually not necessary in non CPU-bound user code.

3. No problem here: they return already completed tasks.

Comment: First point is misleading. The fact that `CancellationTokenSource` is thread-safe is not related to the problem. You still need to synchronize access to the _field_ `quickEntryCancellationTokenSource`, because field is modified (set to null or to a new value) and read from multiple threads.

Comment: Agree. Fix upcoming.

Comment: If i am creating a CancellationTokenSource that is local to that method call how do subsequent method calls access running calls and Cancel them?

Comment: Then pass CancellationTokenSource instead of CancellationToken